# Newest Cycles Renders taking much longer

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I‘m Graphic Designer and work with blender to do renders for my designs. I newly switched to 3.0 and everything was perfect until my last 2 Renders before my renders took like 20 minutes with 4096 Samples and now this render took 3 hours and the next was also the half of the time I turned down the samples and it only took 15 minutes but the quality is bad and I rendered before aswell on 4000 Samples so I don’t think the issue is here. Anyways I hope I can get help because I don’t want to wait 3 hours for a single frame.

Comment: I am sorry but we need more informations to clarify where your problem is, new Cycles should go faster but it may depends on few things... What are your render settings? What is the image size? Are you using single tile? What are you rendering in your scene? What is your GPU? Does your GPU support new Cycles?

Comment: Render Settings: https://imgur.com/GWemId3

Comment: Image Size when you mean pixel size normal 1920x1080 and rendered images size is 8 MB

Comment: I rendered this when it took 3 hours: https://imgur.com/zlKuIVZ

Comment: And my GPU is Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics

Comment: Look at your render settings. You're rendering on CPU. Switch to GPU.

Comment: What @GordonBrinkmann said.  There appears to be a bug in 3.0 that causes it to randomly decide that it can't use the GPU and quietly switch rendering back to CPU only.  I've not been able to consistently reproduce it, so I haven't filed a bug report.  On the other hand, there are definitely scenes where Cycles X is significantly slower than Cycles was.  It appears that the optimizations for complex scenes are pessimizations for some simple scenes.

Comment: @MartyFouts Yeah, I have the same impression that Cycles X is not overall faster. But maybe it's just my old graphics card, I can't compare it with anything else. That switching I didn't experience. I just had the problem that CPU was the default since I didn't copy previous version's settings, and as long as I didn't change the startup file I often forgot to change it before starting to render. But that's just my mistake.